# Generating Rows for each date from start date to end date

Tags: sql, oracle

What I'm trying to do is take a record that looks like this:

```
 Start_DT    End_DT     ID
4/5/2013    10/9/2013    1
```

and change it to look like this:

```
        DT      ID
    4/1/2013    1
    5/1/2013    1
    6/1/2013    1
    7/1/2013    1
    8/1/2013    1
    9/1/2013    1
   10/1/2013    1
```

I am having difficult time making this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with dates (dte, end_mon, id) as (
      select trunc(start_dt, 'MON') as dte, trunc(end_dt, 'MON') as end_mon, id
      from t
      union all
      select dte + interval '1' month, end_mon, id
      from dates
      where dte < end_mon
     )
select *
from dates;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d547d429e3a615abfc807f188187398) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, but similarly - row generator technique is what you're looking for.

(My date format is `DD.MM.YYYY`; can't tell for yours so I'm just guessing as both of your dates can be read in two ways, e.g. 4/5/2013 - is it 4th of May or 5th of April?).

```
SQL> with dates (start_dt, end_dt, id) as
  2    (select date '2013-05-04', date '2013-09-10', 1 from dual)
  3  select start_dt + level - 1 dt, id
  4  from dates
  5  connect by level <= end_dt - start_dt + 1
  6  order by dt;

DT                 ID
---------- ----------
04.05.2013          1
05.05.2013          1
06.05.2013          1
07.05.2013          1
08.05.2013          1
<snip>
06.09.2013          1
07.09.2013          1
08.09.2013          1
09.09.2013          1
10.09.2013          1

130 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `CONNECT BY` to generate the months between each date.

#### Query

```sql
WITH
    dates (start_date, end_date, id)
    AS
        (SELECT TO_DATE ('4/5/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE ('10/9/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 1
           FROM DUAL)
    SELECT TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (start_date, 'MM'), LEVEL - 1), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS dt, id
      FROM dates
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (start_date, 'MM'), LEVEL - 1) <= TRUNC (end_date, 'MM');
```

#### Result

```
           DT    ID
_____________ _____
04/01/2013        1
05/01/2013        1
06/01/2013        1
07/01/2013        1
08/01/2013        1
09/01/2013        1
10/01/2013        1
```